# Angular & Ionic - Access to route parameters

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I need to get the route parameter in my Ionic app.

This is the `app.js` file ( the config section ):

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

            .state('categorylist', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/category_list.html'
            })
            .state('category/single',{
                url: '/maps/:category',
                templateUrl: 'views/mappa.html'
            })

        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    })
```

this is the controller that should get the route parameter and show a map with some marker that will fetch from a online json.
In this section I get the current user position and create some markers on the map.

Right now the `locations` is manually set but in the future it will use the route params to make an API GET request.

How can I access to that params?

```
.controller('MapsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading) {

        $ionicPlatform.ready(onDeviceReady);

        console.log($routeParams);


        function onDeviceReady() {

            // Mostro la finestra di caricamento
            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
            });

            var posOptions = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 50000,
                maximumAge: 0
            };

            var locations = [
                [1, 'Servizio 1', xxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx, 'Address'],
                [2, 'Servizio 2', xxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx, 'Address']
            ];

            // Recupero la posizione dellutente
            $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {

                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var long = position.coords.longitude;

                // Imposto le coordinate
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

                // Impostazioni mappa
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        mapTypeIds: []
                    }
                };

                // Creo la mappa
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

                // Creo il marker con la posizione corrente dell'utente
                var marker;
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });

                marker.setMap(map);


                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                var marker, i;

                // Imposto sulla mappa tutti i servizi trovati
                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
                        map: map
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                        return function () {

                            var popupContent = "<h1>" + locations[i][1] + "</h1>" +
                                "<p>" + locations[i][4] + "</p>";

                            infowindow.setContent(popupContent);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }

                $scope.map = map;
                $scope.elencoServizi = locations;
                $ionicLoading.hide();

                console.log($routeParams);

            }, function (err) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    });
```

I have included `ngRoute` but when I try to print out the `$routeParams` I get an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic framework routing works on the basis of `ui.router`, and then you register all the states of your application using `$stateProvider`.

Where as `ngRoute` is the another way to create route based SPA, at that time `$routeParams` service is used to get value of parameter which passed from URL.

You should use `$stateParams` instead of `$routeParams`

`$stateParmas` has all the information about parameter available in URL.

Answer (score 0):

To access the parameters in links like *xyz/id1/id2*, use the following in *xyz.page.ts* file-

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

..
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute, private router : Router){}

ngOnInit() {
   this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      let id1 = params.get('id1');
      let id2 = params.get('id2');
   });
}
```